# Report validation failed Pentaho

Tags: oracle, tomcat, reporting-services, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have created a report using Pentaho Report Designer. the report data retrieved from Oracle database. Once I upload the report to the pentaho bi server and try to retrieved the report I have this error

> Report validation failed.

pentaho tomcate log shoes this error

```
18:10:09,019 ERROR [AbstractReportProcessor] 1291807259: Report processing failed.
18:10:09,020 ERROR [SimpleReportingComponent] [execute] Component execution failed.
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query: SELECT * FROM testTable
```

Am I missing any library to added it to the tomcat or any configuration that I should change?

would anyone who has come across the error explain how I can overcome it..

Comment: have you kept oracle connector file into the tomcat/libs folder?

Comment: you mean this file @WorkingHard.. , mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar ... its there though

Comment: no. this is for mysql.
same way you have to download and place jdbc connector file for oracle according to your version. example : ojdbc14.jar

Comment: wonderful, it works @WorkingHard..

Comment: i have posted the same as answer.
you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you kept oracle connector file into the tomcat/libs folder?
you have to download and place jdbc connector file for oracle according to your version. example : ojdbc14.jar